# LNK 1106 : invalid file or disk full : cannot seek to 0x4361bd8c

Tags: linker-errors, seek

We have a very old VC++ Application which was actually built using VC++2.2. We have installed VC++4.2 Developer Studio IDE. I'm trying to build the project and getting the following error.

```
libct.lib : fatal error LNK1106: invalid file or disk full: cannot seek to 0x4361bd8c
```

We are actually using Sybase Gateway to connect to the mainframe from this application, which contains the libct.lib and libcs.lib. These are referenced from our project. When I try to build the project getting the above linker error.

I don't know if the version of IDE used to compile is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a problem with the version of the sybase installed. My machine was installed with sybase Open Clien 12.5.1 which is compatible with C/C++ compiler version 6.0 and above. Hence converted the project using VS2008 and the error got cleared out.

Thanks and Regards,
Karthik Sivakumar